# Concurrent iOS Deployments

Tags: ios, developer-program

I would have thought this would be an easy Google search, but I haven't found anything.

I have inherited an existing iPhone app which is currently deployed to the app store (V1.0). I am about to do a bug fix release, V1.1.

I understand that this will take Apple 'time' (a week or two?) to approve.

My question is, while V1.1 is still awaiting approval or rejection, am I allowed to submit V1.2 into a queue? 1.3? Is there a limit?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can submit multiple version to iTunesConnect.  I often create my next 1 or 2 version 'placeholders' in iTC.  Just don't submit the placeholder versions for approval.

Your challenge, if you decide to do this, will be to keep all your versions and source code intact. Because of that, I don't upload the app package until I'm ready to have Apple review it.

Comment: Ummmm [Git](https://git-scm.com/)?

Comment: Yes, he can use Git.  I just said it would be a challenge to have multiple versions of the app submitted to iTC while still maintaining the source code across those versions.  If v1.2 is updated then v1.3 on iTC will need to be changed to reflect those changes, thus invalidating the point of uploading v1.3 to iTC.

Comment: Thanks for this :-)
Yep - I'm GIT obsessed. 
Much appreciated :-)